# What hash function should I use for a bloom-filter with +128-bit keys?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, hash, bloom-filter

https://github.com/joeyrobert/bloomfilter uses Random class for the hash function which is a [performance killer](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Random@cs/1305376/Random@cs).
What I'm trying to do is input the class with byte[]s instead of a generic argument(T) and get rid of

> ```
>     private int Hash(T item) {
>         return item.GetHashCode();
>     }
> ```

I know there is a huge performance benefit but I have no idea how to replace `_random.Next(_bitSize)` here:

```
#region Public Methods
/// <summary>
/// Adds an item to the bloom filter.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="item">Item to be added</param>
public void Add(T item)
{
    _random = new Random(Hash(item));

    for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfHashes; i++)
        _bitArray[_random.Next(_bitSize)] = true;
}
```

With some non-retarded line of code that doesn't take thousands of CPU cycles for every single bit.

I know there are lots of other problems with the code that can make it faster/safer.I have them(mostly) fixed and just got stuck on the last one before pushing my changes.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I have read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753467/using-hash-functions-with-bloom-filters?rq=1 Which I can easily assume is even slower than ``Random''.

Comment: What's funny there, is that the use of `random.Next` is somewhat defeating the purpose of having `_numberOfHashes` in the first place... Because the hashes cease to be _truly_ independent. You could just use a few lightweight hashes (like Fletcher, xxhash, Murmur). Or, since the key is only 128bit... perhaps keep the whole key. (In case I wasn't clear enough: I'd consider losing the Random step alltogether and using a combination of _independent_ hashes directly)

Comment: Also relevant: [Which hashing algorithm is best for uniqueness and speed?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed)

Comment: @sehe:Thanks for the comments.The thing is that in my case input values are precomputed sha1 values and are completely unique.I just don't know how to convert an arbitrary length array to _numberOfHashes integers and not loose speed, precision and my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I lack to see why you would want to use a random number generator here... however, I can help you to speed things up.

A bloom filter is basically a bitvector, where you set bits. If you want to figure out if an item exists, the bloom filter will give you a true if the item *possibly exists* and a false if the item *for sure doesn't exist*.

(I'm doing this in a simple text editor so there might be some bugs in the code)

I'm going to assume your hash space here can use 32-bit integer calculations; if you have a very large bloom table, you probably want to use a 64-bit integer.

The easiest (and probably the fastest) implementation of a bloom filter is thus:

```
byte[] bloomFilter = new byte[MyBloomFilterSize];

foreach (var item in myItems) 
{
    int hash = Hash(item) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
    int bit = 1 << (hash & 7); // you have 8 bits
    int index = (hash >> 3) % MyBloomFilterSize;
    bloomFilter[hash % MyBloomFilterSize] |= bit;
}
```

You can experiment with changing the `byte[]` to a `uint[]` or a `ulong[]`; I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

If you then want to check if an item might exist, you calculate the same index and bit, and get the result.

```
public bool PossiblyExists(MyItem item)
{
    int hash = Hash(item) & 0x7FFFFFFF;

    int bit = 1 << (hash & 7); // you have 8 bits
    int index = (hash >> 3) % MyBloomFilterSize;
    return (bloomFilter[hash % MyBloomFilterSize] & bit) != 0;
}
```

The only thing that remains here is the speed at which you can calculate the hash. If you're using an integer, I'd simply multiply it with a large prime number; if you're using a SHA256 fixed-length byte[] (which you seem to be doing), you need to make it an integer (or long).

I'm using a little trick here with Buffer.BlockCopy to convert the types. Just for safety I prefer using a few bytes from the data, but since SHA256 should already be random, a simple `BitConverter.ToInt32(data, [0..28])` should also do the trick.

```
public int CalculateHash(byte[] data) 
{
    // Data = >128 bits = >16 bytes -- which is the same as >4 integers

    int[] tmp = new int[4];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, tmp, 0, data.Length);
    return tmp[0] ^ tmp[1] ^ tmp[2] ^ tmp[3];
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing it completely wrong with that _random thing. ty for the answer, the project is still in development and you just gave me a new idea to change things.

Comment: It wasn't giving me random data though, I was just using it as a complicated hash function.(I had read the internal code back then)

Comment: Yes, I noticed the seed, it just didn't make a lot of sense. Anyhow, HTH.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient implementation would be for example the following. If you have a hash function that returns 64 bit, then better use this instead of murmur3_64. Warning: I didn't test it.

```
void Add(string item) {
    ulong hash = murmur3_64((ulong) item.GetHashCode());
    uint a = (uint) (hash >> 32);
    uint b = (uint) hash;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        _bitArray[reduce(a, _bitSize)] = true;
        // "Less Hashing, Same Performance: Building a Better Bloom Filter"
        a += b;
    }
}

ulong murmur3_64(ulong x) {
    x = (x ^ (x >> 33)) * 0xff51afd7ed558ccdL;
    x = (x ^ (x >> 23)) * 0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53L;
    x = x ^ (x >> 33);
    return x;
}

uint reduce(uint hash, uint n) {
    // http://lemire.me/blog/2016/06/27/a-fast-alternative-to-the-modulo-reduction/
    return (hash * n) >> 32;
}
```